# DynamoDB Scan ignoring uppercase or lowercase letters

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, case, dynamodb-queries, ignore-case

My boss asked me to make a filter that does not recognize upper and lower case letters and I added the following code that makes the filter but recognizes the use of upper and lower case letters and does not find anything

```
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);
    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    Map<String, String> ean = new HashMap<String, String>();

    StringJoiner where = new StringJoiner(" and ");
    if (status != null) {
        eav.put(":status", new AttributeValue().withS(status));
        where.add("#status = :status");
        ean.put("#status", "status");
        scanExpression.withExpressionAttributeNames(ean);
    }
   if (where.length() > 0) {
                            scanExpression.withFilterExpression(where.toString()).withExpressionAttributeValues(eav).withConsistentRead(false);
        }

        // Scan to the end of the page after the requested page
        int scanTo = (int) (pageable.getOffset() + (2 * pageable.getPageSize()));
```

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB it's case-sensitive right now, as you can see in this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=92159).

An alternative way to make this search would be to save another field with upper/lower case and change your search to this field.

Comment: Right. If you listen to DynamoDB developers describe this product, one insight you'll get again and again is that when using DynamoDB, you are expected to plan your data model carefully - based on what types of queries you expect to get. You often add additional attributes and even secondary indexes especially to serve specific types of queries - and in your case you can add a lowercased version of an attribute as a second attribute, to be used in queries that want to be case-agnostics.